# How to Pass record type values to record type parameter in a procedure/function

Tags: oracle, plsql, user-defined-types

```
procedure P_names(  A OUT NOCOPY  A_Rec_Type
                     ,  B  OUT NOCOPY B_Tbl_Type);
```

In the above PL/SQL procedure how to pass values to the parameters A and B which are record type
and table type parameters?

Comment: PLEASE DON'T WRITE IN ALL UPPERCASE - it's considering SHOUTING and it's **rude to your peers**

Answer (score 1):

Because they are OUT parameters you need to call them with PL/SQL variables, like this:

```
declare
    lrt_a A_Rec_Type;
    lrt_b B_Tbl_Type;
begin
    p_names (lrt_a, lrt_b);
end;
/
```

Internally you assign values to them like any other variable.  Because these are record types the normal expectation is that you would populate them with a query:

```
begin
    select * into a
    from table_a
    where rownum = 1;

    select * into b
    from table_b
    where rownum = 1;
end;
```

Note that I used ROWNUM there.  That's because record types accept a single row, so you need to restrict the query appropriately.  If you want to accept multiple rows then you need to use a nested table type instead:

```
type a_recs_type is table of a_rec_type;
```

Comment: @Ian - the cool thing about programming is that we don't have to believe something to be true: we can just write some code and discover whether it is in fact true. Why don't you try it? You might be surprised :)

Comment: I was trying this specific issue for the last day and a half, and all the online samples I found to be working pass a table as parameter. The online samples that I saw that I saw that pass one record type, use the RECORD keyword and are really old, 2010 - 2012. My version of Oracle uses <type of object> kind of construct. So I did do my due dilligence. If I am wrong, then I will delete my comment.

Comment: @Ian - We can define stored procedure parameters using any datatype we can use to define variables within stored procedure bodies. I admit I interpreted your comment to refer to types defined by the `record` keyword. What other *"record type"* construct are you trying to use? It sounds like you need to ask a new question. Please include details of what you're trying to achieve and what you've done so far. Incidentally, 'record` types where introduced at same time as nested tables and other object types. The difference is they are **PL/SQL only** whereas CREATE TYPE types are SQL objects.

Comment: You are right. I forgot what was my test scenario, I went with a different solution. But I have created this script, and it worked from the first time./*
create or replace type type_1 
IS OBJECT (
  ID  integer,
  name varchar2(10)
);
function fn_1(in_rec type_1) return integer
is
begin
    return in_rec.ID;
end;
*/

declare

var1 type_1 := type_1(null,null);
tempVariable integer;

begin

    select type_1(1,'one')
    into var1
    from dual;
    
    tempVariable := TSLIP_PROCESSING_PKG.fn_1(var1);
    
    dbms_output.put_line(tempVariable);

end;

Answer (score 0):

use something like

```
a(i).field_name := <your value>


b.field_name := <your value> ;
```

where i is index in your table